# Random css class from nowhere

Tags: html, css

I have a problem on a page i'm coding. Problem is i'm getting random img classes from nowhere (at least nowhere i know). I've put the generated class below.

```
<img class=" iryjanjabqqmypymdnuv" src="some/source/path">
```

There are several jquery plugins and jqueryui on the page but div that got img has nothing to do with those js libs. I also use php but that must have nothing to do with this i guess.

If you need any codes or names of the libraries just ask. Please help me i really have no idea and all the search i did was empty about this.

Comment: Needs more info, preferably a live link

Comment: Can you show the `<link>` and `<script>` tags you're using to fetch code from elsewhere?

Comment: Do you see that in your html when you "View Source" in your browser? Then it's generated serverside, and so you should look at your PHP code. Otherwise it might be a library generating the class name.

Comment: try to disable all JS and then, check if there is still that class

Comment: Disabled js with developer toolbar it's still giving that class. And yes its causing problems because i cant see that image :).
I've checked php files and i'm not using any external php classes its all the programming i've done. script is fetching data from mysql data base and printing divs in a loop. Any ideas what should i be looking for in php files ?

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem. Find out that **AdBlock Plus** is responsible for that. So, just disable all the extensions and reload the page

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to chime in for anyone that finds this googling their problem, this is exactly the right answer in my case as well.  AdBlock Plus (in Firefox only, not Chrome) was generating random class names for images I have embedded in my nav bar for social media links.

Now I have to either find a way to get around that or anyone using ABP in Firefox will see a weird looking nav bar due to this issue.  It's not exactly an unpopular plugin.

I work in both Chrome and Firefox and use ABP in both.  Hopefully we won't have to find workarounds for this.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you're browsing on a mobile network connection? Some mobile networks modify the HTML/CSS for images so they can serve lower-bandwidth versions, but allow you to "fix" them later. For example, on T-Mobile, if I hover over an image it will give me an Alt tag telling me the keyboard shortcut to use to load the original.

Obviously this won't be the case if it's all local...

Comment: It's not mobile. I'm using Firefox 6.0.2 files located on remote server.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and disabled all extensions in Firefox and then it was gone. Not sure which extension is the guilty party, have too many to chase it down by disabling each of them one at a time. :)